# IRDA SIR Programming for Windows or Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I am trying to write code on Linux or Windows that talks via IRDA SIR to an external embedded device.  I want to send bytes like through a serial port, as the embedded device treats its IRDA interface as a simple serial port.  The IRDA adapter on my computer uses the MosChip MCS7780 device, so it plugs into a USB port.

On Windows, I've been able to install the drivers, and Device Manager sees it correctly; however, I'm not sure how to talk to it in C++.  I was hoping to treat it as a serial port, but it doesn't show up like that in Device Manager - it shows up as a "USB-Infrared Adapter".  How do I write software that uses such a device?

On Linux, the supplied drivers would not build without a few tweaks, but that seems to work now.  However, I am again stuck when it comes to writing the software.  How do I get started there?

Ideally, both platforms would be useful, though one is (infinitely) better than none!

Comment: it looks that people are not interested in irDA anymore. I also have the same problem.